# I can't locate correct Python script to update

Tags: python, command-line, compiler-construction, command-line-interface, python-2.6

I have a script that I am running at `/var/scripts/SomeAppName/source/importer/processor.py`

That script triggers an error that has a line that says:

`File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/something/cms/browser.py", line 43, in GetBrowser`

The problem I'm running into is that I'm unable to locate `build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/something/cms/browser.py` but I can locate `/var/scripts/AnotherApp/appcommon/cms/browser.py` and `/var/scripts/AnotherApp/build/lib/appcommon/cms/browser.py`

I have modieified both of those files to remove the part that is throwing the error but am still getting the same error as if the file hasn't been modified at all.

I'm guessing the problem is that I'm not modifying the correct file or I need to compile the script some how but I'm just not able to find out where/how to do this.

I have tried restarting `apache` but with no luck.

Any help or guidance as to where I should be looking or if I need to run some sort of command to re-compile to browser.py file would be appreciated.

Comment: that looks like you installed this app with `setup.py install`, in which case you'll need to run that again to see any changes.  i'm curious how you deployed this and why you're editing it live...  :)

Comment: Are you running with the right version of Python? What's the error type?

Comment: @Eevee, It looks like your suggestion is what I was looking for. If you post it in the form of an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the loop: `bdist` in the path is a sign that the package was installed with `setup.py install` and is running from the standard Python system path, not from wherever you have it checked out.

Easy fix is to `setup.py install` it again.

Harder fix is to uninstall it and fiddle with Apache's working directory, but that's not quite my area.  :)